# Case statement - cannot nest aggregate operations

Tags: sql, teradata

I am getting an error -

> can not nest aggregate operations when trying to run the below part of the query in Teradata.

When SeqCount = 2 and surgery data is the same as the first surgery, I want the 2nd surgery date (SecondSurgery) to be null else return the 2nd surgery data.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
SELECT
    pat_id,
    PatientMRN,
    PatientName,
    AdmitDate,
    DischargeDate,
    MIN(case when SeqCount=1 then ORProcName else null end) as FirstProcedure,
    MIN(case when SeqCount=1 then SurgeryDate else null end) as FirstSurgery,
    MIN(case when SeqCount=2 then ORProcName else null end) as SecondProcedure,
    MIN(case when SeqCount=2 and SurgeryDate = FirstSurgery then NULL  else SurgeryDate end) as SecondSurgery
```

Comment: Your usage of `MIN` without `GROUP BY`, and while selecting other non aggregate columns, does not make sense.  Please provide sample data and expected output.

Comment: You probably want a combination of `qualify row_number() over (partition by pat_id order by SurgeryDate) = 1` and `lead` (or a `min`) `over` replacing aggregation

Comment: Please provide full query for better understanding of your problem.

Comment: Your query has no nested aggregation functions and is incomplete.  Show (a perhaps simplified form of) your query that illustrates the problem.

Comment: The CASE statement for `SecondSurgery` references `FirstSurgery` which is an aggregation. Could this be where you are going sideways?

Answer (score 0):

as the ErrorMsg is saying it's not possible due to the SET-based processing (all at once). - You can force an sequential processing with sub-queries and calculate SecondSurgery in the outer-SQL.